# How do I refer to all components of a list with a single function in R?

Tags: r, list

I have split my df into a list containing 500 groups thus:

```
c1=cut(SNP_Allele_Frequency$College_SE,500)
splitc1=split(SNP_Allele_Frequency,c1,drop=FALSE)
```

I need to find the mean for a variable for all the 500 groups (levels) contained in the list CL. Instead of repeating the process 500 times (as below), is there a way I can do this with one function?

```
mean(splitc1[[1L]]$ACB)....mean(splitc1[[2L]]$ACB)...
mean(splitc1[[500L]]$ACB)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's make some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(24)
SNP_Allele_Frequency <- data.frame(College_SE = rnorm(1000), ACB = rnorm(1000))
```

Now using your original method:

```
c1 <- cut(SNP_Allele_Frequency$College_SE, 50)
splitc1 <- split(SNP_Allele_Frequency, c1, drop = FALSE)
lapply(splitc1, function(x) mean(x[["ACB"]]))
```

We could do it more cleanly in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
SNP_Allele_Frequency %>% mutate(c1 = cut(SNP_Allele_Frequency$College_SE, 50)) %>%
                         group_by(c1) %>%
                         summarise(meanACB = mean(ACB))
```

Comment: I really like that you answered with both base and a library. Kudos!

Comment: There is also a base-R method that does not require splitting into a list of df: `tapply(SNP_Allele_Frequency$ACB,cut(SNP_Allele_Frequency$College_SE, 50))`